# What Is The Difference Between Functions Definitions And Class Definitions

Tags: scala, methods, constructor, case-class

I came across this situation.

```
class Test(a: List[Int])(b: a.type) //This won't compile
def test(a: List[Int])(b: a.type) = ??? //This will compile
```

Can someone please explain to me why this is?

Comment: @slouc http://i.imgur.com/fmbLCEn.png. This is the error I'm getting in the console.

Comment: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5712

Comment: doesn't compile on 2.11.8

Answer (score 0):

It's not a function definition, it's a method definition. The other one is a class definition. The feature is called dependent method types. In other words: its a feature of methods. A class is not a method.

Comment: The semantics don't matter. It's still a feature that should be there. This doesn't answer my question at all. Please look here: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5712.